# How to get the all highlighted text inside ace editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

I have a question regarding ace editor. Below is my question.

Whenever I find inside the ace editor using RegExp or any mode we could see the all matched words are highlighted using the css .ace_selected_word.

For example, if I apply `RegEx \d+` it will highlight all integer values inside the editor.

How to retrieve that all highlighted text from ace editor.

I have tried using `editor.getSelectedText()` but it's giving me the only the entered string to find.

Could anyone give me a suggestion on this?

Comment: How are you initiating editor in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

there is no method in ace to do that, but you can do

```
editor.getValue().match(/\d+/g)
```

or

```
editor.getValue().match(editor.$search.$options.re)
```

Another option is to use find all button to select all highlighted words, and then use `editor.getSelectedText()`

Comment: In ace editor find search box whenever we type the string it will highlighted all the corresponding matches. We don't need to trigger any button explicitly.

Comment: indeed, occurrences in the visible part of the text are highlighted automatically, but not stored. How is that related to your question or to my answer?